# Regular Expression Numeric Range Fails in Perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl

My script needs to find a specific linux kernel version using regular expressions - 3.13.0-24-generic.

I tried:

```
'((2\.[46])|(3\.[0-99])\.\d[^\/]*?) \(.*@.*\) [#]\d+.*'
```

but it doesn't work. How can I match my kernel version? Why does the regex above fail to match 3.13.0-24-generic?

Additional Info Based on Comments: 
I am editing a SystemImager UseYourOwnKernel.pm script. The original script checks for either a 2.4 or 2.6 kernel:

```
my $regex =
#           | kernel version + build machine
#           `---------------------------------------
            '(2\.[46]\.\d[^\/]*?) \(.*@.*\) [#]\d+.*' .
```

3.0,1,2, (i.e. single digit 3.X kernels) work with:

```
'((2\.[46])|(3\.[012])\.\d[^\/]*?) \(.*@.*\) [#]\d+.*'
```

I can get it to match the 3.13 and (3.0, 3.1, 3.2, etc) kernel using:

```
'((2\.[46])|(3\.[012]|3\.13)\.\d[^\/]*?) \(.*@.*\) [#]\d+.*' .
```

I need a numeric range that will match from 3.0 to 3.99 (this should take care of all 3.X releases).

Comment: What is `\(.*@.*\) [#]` there for? The kernel version you're trying to match has no `(`, `@`, `)`, or `#` characters, so this regex will very obviously not match. The regex also has spaces in it, which won't match either.

Comment: And `[^\/]*` -- why is that there? Match anything except forward slashes? There's no reason for `/` to appear in the regex.

Comment: `[0-99]` is not a "numeric range". It's a *character class* that represents a single character. It says to accept any character between `0` and `9`, and then it has another `9` in it that has no purpose, so it's identical to `[0-9]`. On the same note, `[46]` will match a single character, either a `4` or a `6`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])-(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])-\w+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aP7bV1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])` Matches any number from 0-99.
- `\.` A literal dot.
- `-` A literal `-`

**OR**

A much shorter one,

```
(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.){2}(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])-){2}\w+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yN0pW3)

Comment: Just what I needed! Full line for others trying to do the same thing: '((2\.[46])|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.\d[^\/]*?) \(.*@.*\) [#]\d+.*' .

Comment: I don't know why `@#` comes inside a kernal version output.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you:

```
(?:(?:[\d]|[1-9][\d])\.){2}(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])-){2}\w+
```

Comment: Any explanation of what it does?

Comment: (?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]) Matches numbers from 0-99

\. A literal dot.

- A literal-